# Solving reaction-diffusion system with Theano

Tags: python, scipy, theano

I am new to Theano, and I try to implement a numerical integrator of a reaction-diffusion system - [FitzHugh–Nagumo model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitzHugh%E2%80%93Nagumo_model) of this version:

[image]

[image]

For now my expressions are:

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T

u = T.dmatrix('u')
v = T.dmatrix('v')
e = T.dscalar('e')
a0 = T.dscalar('a0')
a1 = T.dscalar('a1')

dudt = u - u**3 -v
dvdt = e*(u - a1*v - a0)
```

So I haven't implemented the finite-differences [laplacian operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator#Finite_Differences) yet. My question is whether there is a smart way of doing it in Theano?

Comment: What is your spatial domain, and what are the boundary conditions?

Comment: My spatial domain is 2D, so `v` and `u` are functions of `(x,y)`. For now I am studying periodic boundary conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason for using Theano? There are other ways in Python to solve a system of coupled non-linear ODEs.

The reaction-diffusion system definition from Google seems to suggest that u(x,y,t), v(x,y,t).

I am not a user of Theano, but it looks like casting the problem in the form of an equation like b = Ax is the way to go.

Some resources that I came across on Google for using Theano and generally solving PDEs are below.

[Expressing the Laplacian using Theano](http://www.ericlwilkinson.com/blog/2015/1/11/numerical-relaxation-on-the-gpu-with-theano)

[Solving a reaction-diffusion problem using numpy](http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-05/)

[Github project using Theano to solve the shallow water PDE](https://github.com/mrocklin/ShallowWater)

Comment: The third link is really helpful

Comment: [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) is also a possible option and perhaps simpler than `theano` for this?

Answer (score 2):

An interesting example of a similar, but simpler problem, solved using convolutional networks on Google's tensorflow can be found here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/pdes/index.html

In particular they use the following definition of the diffusion kernel:

```
  laplace_k = make_kernel([[0.5, 1.0, 0.5],
                           [1.0, -6., 1.0],
                           [0.5, 1.0, 0.5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two coupled, first order, non-linear, ordinary differential equations here.

Update: Now your equations are clear - Laplacians are there; two coupled nonlinear PDEs.  *Much* better.

You need a finite difference or finite element approach for your spatial discretization.  Your choice, of course, but I'd prefer a finite element approach over finite differences.

You also need some kind of numerical integration in time.  An implicit error correcting scheme would be best.

I looked quickly at the Theano docs.  I didn't see anything to help you with your spatial discretization problem.  Once you accomplish that you'll have matrix equations that you can solve, but I don't believe Theano will help you formulate the problem.

I'll admit that I'm not a Theano maven.